# Devicepath and USB device

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, opencv, usb

I am using OpenCV and videoInput library on Windows 7. My PC has more webcams connected and they are of the same type. VideoInput library can differentiate them according to their device path or by their friendly name; unfortunately I cannot use the latter, since it is  identical for all. I wonder if there is a simple way in C++ to scan all my USB devices and  associate for each of them its device path to the position inside USB three, namely for example

*device path -> root 1, port 4*

I thank you in advance!
Best
G.

Comment: This is much more related to the Windows platform than OpenCV.